# textview click event in dialogbox

Tags: android, dialog

I want text click event in a `dialogbox`. but when I click on image it shouts down...
when I should click on the link it should move to the browser and open that link...
please help...

this is my code:

```
ivworkshivalik.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Ourwork.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.shivalik);
            dialog.setTitle("SHIVALIK PROJECTS");


            TextView tvshivalik1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik1);
            TextView tvshivalik2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik2);
            tvshivalik2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.shivalikprojects.com/"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: clear your question first?

Comment: there is a text in a dialogbox in which there is a link for a website... when i click on that text it shoul move to that site through browser....

Comment: @akky777 you forgot to initialize the textview the same way as the first. also you should post the stack trace

Comment: Is your `tvshivalik2` declared in your `shivalik` layout ?

Comment: @akky777 "but when I click on image it shouts down." where is the image in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace this

```
 TextView tvshivalik2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik2);
```

With

```
 TextView tvshivalik2 =(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Insted of this

```
TextView tvshivalik2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik2);
```

you should try

```
TextView tvshivalik2 =(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize as below. The same way you initialized `tvshivalik1`

```
 TextView tvshivalik2 =(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvshivalik2);
```

assuming your `shivalik.xml` has a textview with id `tvshivalik2`.